# How can I filter out text from a date column?

Tags: looker-studio, date-formatting

I have a column in Google Data Studio, which looks like this:

| Date | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL |
| 2022-01-01 11:44:19 | 9 |
| 2022-01-03 06:03:26 | 3 |
| 2022-02-03 06:03:26 | 4 |
| 2022-02-03 13:39:52 | 5 |
| 2022-03-03 13:41:33 | 2 |

The desired date format is dd/mm/yyyy (I don't really need the HMS). I'm trying to get the sum of each rating by month.

[Sample data is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nsJOvaszrcVjWsnYT5ozbDu8U-R0iomIphHiSUoIJVI/edit?usp=sharing).

[Sample report is here.](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1c326740-caa0-451c-b314-9ce77e4091a0)

The "NULL" is not actually a `null` value but text. Because of this, the entire column is being treated as a text field. Is there a function that would ignore the "NULL" text values and only consider the dates, thus treating the field as a date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A three step approach is to first create a new date field (titled `Date_Calc` below), then [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) out `NULL` values and finally change the field type from the default `Date & Time` to `Date` at the [data source-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=over%20the%20other.-,Calculated%20fields%20in%20data%20sources,-When%20you%20create) and to `Month` at the [chart-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=calculated%20fields%20there.-,Chart%2Dspecific%20calculated%20fields,-You%20can%20add):

## 1) `Date_Calc`

Create the [data source-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=over%20the%20other.-,Calculated%20fields%20in%20data%20sources,-When%20you%20create) [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below which uses the [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) function to "*convert text to a date with time*", with the input `%F %T`, where `%F` represent "*the date in the format `%Y-%m-%d`*" and `%T` is "*the time in the format `%H:%M:%S`*"; additionally, the function ensures that other values such as the text "*NULL*" would be converted to `NULL` values:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%F %T", Date)
```

## 2) [Filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066)

```
Exclude Date_Calc Is NULL
```

## 3) Additional Changes

This section looks at a core requirement (field type) as well as a few optional changes that could be made at the [data source-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=over%20the%20other.-,Calculated%20fields%20in%20data%20sources,-When%20you%20create):

- ***Field Type***: Change the field type of the `Date_Calc` field from `Date & Time` to `Date` at the [data source-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=over%20the%20other.-,Calculated%20fields%20in%20data%20sources,-When%20you%20create); the granularity can then further be changed at the [chart-level](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685#:%7E:text=calculated%20fields%20there.-,Chart%2Dspecific%20calculated%20fields,-You%20can%20add) (such as to `Quarter`, `Year`, `Year Month` or in this case, `Month`)
- ***Hide Fields***: The current text field, `Date` could be hidden at the data source
- ***Rename Fields***: The hidden `Date` field could be renamed to `Date_Original` and the `Date_Calc` field could be renamed to `Date`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3d56865c-d282-458a-b2b1-8e51ef4b4d0e) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxA-k9qZaa6BiNpM2HIoDimCgucQRvmfTU1wS_BmdVQ/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 8]

Answer (score -1):

Consider create a calculated field that has the following formula:

```
IF(LENGTH(Date)=4,"",Date)
```

Where "4" is the lenght of "NULL" word.

The previous formula checks the length of the `Date` field and (*if the lenght is the same as the lenght of the `NULL` value*), then, set a empty string<sup>1</sup>; otherwise, keep the original value of the `Date` value.

In [your report example](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1c326740-caa0-451c-b314-9ce77e4091a0), I've created a field called `NewField` - which has the described formula above.

---

<sup>1</sup> Instead of an empty string, you can set a default value, like `0001-01-01` or set another default value according to your needs.

Comment: While this answer converts the text "*NULL*" to `NULL` values, it does not answer the 2 primary questions: 1) Converting the field type of the `Date` field from Text to Date 2) Removing the `NULL` rows